# Efficiently combine two queries with both have a common inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join three tables and then union them.  Two of the table that are joined are the same in the two queries which are union'd, and it seems like a waste to perform this join twice.  See below for an example.  How is this best performed?  Thanks

```
SELECT t1.c1,t2.c1,t3.c1
FROM audits AS t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.t1_id=t1.id
WHERE t2.fk1=123
UNION
SELECT t1.c1,t2.c1,t4.c1
FROM audits AS t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.t1_id=t1.id
WHERE t2.fk1=123
ORDER BY t1.fk1 ASC
```

Comment: This solution is fine

Comment: @zerkms  Yes, it works, but you are doing the same query twice.  Can it be done once as a subquery?  Using outer joins for T3 and T4 on the same t1/t2 inner join will work, but will not provide the records individually.

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. If you're concerned about performance, think about using [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views.html) (;

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao: views **cannot** improve performance, by definition.

Comment: @user1032531: does it fit the application performance requirements? If it does - don't waste your time. PS: "as fast as possible" isn't a requirement

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao  I've heard mixed messages whether views can improve speed.  Are they somehow stored in different memory?

Comment: @zerkms  More hypothetical than real application, and I just want to know what is best practice.

Comment: @user1032531: the best practice is to write the most readable query as possible at first. I hardly doubt that in mysql you may write it better.

Comment: @user1032531: view is just a special kind of object that stores a query. So it does nothing but stores a query for you. And when you select from it - it performs a query is if it was done by you manually.

Comment: @zerkms You're right. *Live and learn.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work, if the syntax is supported by MySql, and might be slightly more efficient:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1, t.c1
FROM audits AS t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
INNER JOIN (
  select t1_id from t3
  union
  select t1_id from t4
) as t ON t.t1_id=t1.id
WHERE t2.fk1=123
ORDER BY t1.fk1 ASC
```

The reason for a pssible performance improvement is the smaller footprint of the relation being UNION'ed; one column instead of 3. UNION eliminates duplicates (unlike UNION ALL) so the entire collection of records must be sorted to eliminate duplicates.

At the meta-level this query informs the optimizer of a specific optimization available, that it may be unable to determine on it's own.

Comment: "and might be slightly more efficient" --- if only this subquery is optimized well. And as we all know (?) - mysql optimizes subqueries not as ideally as we'd wanted.

Comment: @zerkms: See my addendum. It's not whether the subquery is optimized; it's whether the optimizer sees through to perform the same optimization on the original query.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens please take a look [here](http://pastie.org/7489957). It may be more efficient, since it filters *t2* before joining tables *t3* and *t*. So what you think?

Comment: @user1032531 maybe the query optimizer does the job; but would you care to make some tests using code above and this update [here](http://pastie.org/7489957)? (guessing your tables are populated)